# The parameterized query expects the parameter (C#)

Tags: c#

I created school project with ID and password login system connected to SQL database. In student there is not problem. but when i try login as teacher there is an error like this :

** The parameterized query '(@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 nvarchar(4000))select * from teachers wh' expects the parameter '@p1', which was not supplied.**

```cs
public string ID, password;

private void teacherform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  con.Open();

  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from teachers where t_id = @p1 and t_password=@p2", con);
  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ID);
  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", password);
  SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
  if (dr.Read()) {
    teacherform tf = new teacherform();
    tf.Show();
    this.Hide();
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("ID or password incorrect!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
  con.Close();
}
```

Error looks like that:

[image: ErrorScreenshot]

I want to login as a teacher with password and ID.

Comment: I understand that this is a school project, but still: NEVER store passwords in plain in a database. Use salted hashes instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Something is not clear here. I suppose that _teacherform_Load_ is binded to the load event of each teacherform form class instances. But then you create a new _teacherform_ instance if the password is correct and hide the current form. Where is located this event? In which form?

Answer (score 3):

If either of those values are `null` then the parameter does not get passed at all. You need to coalesce it with `DBNull.Value`.

Furthermore

- You should not cache conenction objects. Create when needed and dispose when done with a `using`.
- The command and reader also need `using`.
- The reader itself is actually not necessary. You just want to check existence so use `ExecuteScalar`
- And you don't need `select *`, just return `select 1`.
- I sincerely hope you are not storing passwords in plain text. Salt-and-hash them, and store them as bianry (byte array) values.
- Don't use `AddWithValue`, pass the parameters as their exact type, *including length*.
- Sensible parameter names would make sense.

```cs
private void teacherform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string query = @"
select 1
from teachers
where t_id = @id
  and t_password = @passHash;
";
    using var con = new SqlConnection(YourConnString);
    using var com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    com.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ID ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
    com.Parameters.Add("@passHash", SqlDbType.VarBinary, 128).Value = SaltAndHashPassword(ID, password) ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
    con.Open();
    var result = com.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
    con.Close();
    if(result)
    {
        teacherform tf = new teacherform();
        tf.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ID or password incorrect!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```